# SVN folder renamed

Tags: svn, version-control

I am working on a branch of a project that is checked into SVN.  The branch was created in a sub folder of a folder called branch.  I renamed the branch folder to branches after working on, but not checking in, the code within the aforementioned branch.  Now, when I try to check in, I understandably, get an error saying that the path in SVN cannot be found.  How do I resolve this issue?

Thanks,

Sachin

Comment: Did you use SVN rename and not your native OS rename?

Comment: rename it back to `branch` commit any changes rename it to `branches` and check-out again

Comment: I went to repo browser and then changed it from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename the folder back, then do a svn move on the folder.

Other techniques exist, but this is probably the easiest.

Comment: Some SVN clients, such as TortoiseSVN, provide an SVN rename option.

Comment: @JMack The TortiseSVN client provides a menu option called "rename", but actually it is just a `svn move oldname newname` command.